# Showing a set is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Show that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus  \{(0,0)\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I'm not sure if this is obvious I can't give enough details. Every point in $U=D(v,||v||)$ has a $\epsilon$-neighbourhood contained in U such that $v=(a,b)\ne (0,0)$.

Can someone please help me on describing the details? Than you.

Comment: Ok so you know what to show but can you give a value for $\epsilon$ (dependent on $v$)?

Comment: Can you use that the complement of a closed set is an open one? Do you know that each singleton in the usual topology in $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you proved that open disks are topologically open? If you have (or if you can), then it follows that $D(v,\lVert v\rVert)$ will be an open neighborhood of $v$ contained in $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ for any $v\in\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}.$

Comment: Yes I have and that's exactly what I was missing here.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a point $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 - \{0\}$.  Then put $\eta = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}/2$.  Using the triangle inequality, you should be able to show that 
$\{(s,t)| d((s,t), (x,y)) < \eta\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 - \{0\}.$